# How to group multiple views in a ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

I have added 3 buttons in a ConstraintLayout. I have added a button to disable or enable these buttons.

If I was using normal LinearLayout. I could have put all the buttons in a Linear Layout and enable or disable that particular layout.

But I am using ConstraintLayout. So I need to disable or enable all of these buttons, I believe that there must be a way in ConstraintLayout to group different views.

Kindly guide me how to group views in ConstriantLayout

[image]

```
  <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />
```

Comment: Take a look, maybe Chains might help you: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#Chains

Comment: setGroupVisibility(mLayout, group, Group.VISIBLE) ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47865436/cant-set-visibility-on-constraint-group

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Yes, as I know you can handle visibility using linear layout but not Enable/Disable views I think, correct me if I am wrong. So now in **ConstraintLayout** also we can handle visibility of particular group of views using the **Group**

**<android.support.constraint.Group/>**

> This is new feature introduced in ConstraintLayout which is currently
> in Beta version.

How to add beta ConstraintLayout to project follow steps below

**add maven support in project gradle file as below**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**then in app gardle dependencies add ConstarintLayout library dependency**

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta3'
```

**now you have to add group in your ConstraintLayout as follow**

```
<android.support.constraint.Group
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="button7,button3,button2"
        android:id="@+id/group" />
```

**where in Group reference id**

```
app:constraint_referenced_ids="button7,button3,button2"
```

contains the **comma separated view id's you want to handle run time**, so in activity you just bind Group as below and handle visibility

```
import android.support.constraint.Group; //import statement in activity

Group group=(Group)findViewById(R.id.group);//bind view from xml
group.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//this will visible all views
group.setVisibility(View.GONE);//this will set Gone to all views
group.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);//this will set INVISIBLE to all view
```

**Edit: ConstraintLayout 1.1.0 stable version released on 12 April 2018**
https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2018/04/constraintlayout-110.html

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
```

**Edit: Android X
If anyone using android x package you can find package info here**

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

and use:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group />
```

Comment: Is it Possible to change the background color for group ?

Comment: @IbrahimDisouki i think it is not there currently, if anything i found i will update here.

Comment: It's not possible. Groups were created to control its members visibility, not view positioning or anything like that.

Comment: Yes as group reference views position can be anywhere on the screen so technically it does not make any sense

Comment: can `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group` be used on Views not part of a Constraintlayout?

Comment: The answer to my question above is, no. Also you can't just place a `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group` anywhere in your layout file, it must share the same parent `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` as the Views it references.

Answer (score 3):

Currently there is no way you can do that. You have to disable each button individually, because constraints are added to each widget in constraintlayout.

To group views, you need to use view groups, that doesn't make sense in the context of constraint layout.

**Edit**

With Constraint layout:1.1.0-beta1, you can group views using `android.support.constraint.Group`.