# Can't set visibility on constraint group

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout, kotlin-android-extensions

When i try to set the visibility of the group on button click,it doesn't affect the view's visibility.Using com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta4. I've tried setting it element-wise without problems,but no success with the group.

**My MainActivity.kt**

```
private fun toggleLoginUI(show: Boolean) {
    if (show) {
        group.visibility = VISIBLE
    } else {
        group.visibility = INVISIBLE
    }
}

fun onClick(view: View) {
    when (view.id) {
        R.id.button -> toggleLoginUI(true)
        R.id.button4 -> toggleLoginUI(false)
    }
}
```

**My activity_main.xml**

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout..

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
... />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
... />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
.../>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
... />


            <android.support.constraint.Group
                android:id="@+id/group"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView,textView2" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44449495/toggle-visibility-of-chain-group-in-constraint-layout)

Comment: whats the problem give the log

Comment: there is no error in the log.it just doesn't do anything

Comment: Was beating my head with screen to figure this out.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Update:** This was reported as fixed in ConstraintLayout version 2.0.0 beta 6. See [bug fixes for ConstraintLayout 2.0.0 beta 6](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/05/constraintlayout-200-beta-6.html) .

---

---

This looks like a bug to me. `GONE` works but `INVISIBLE` doesn't and I think it should. It may be worth a bug report unless someone can post where my thinking is wrong. (I am using `constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta4`.)

In the meantime, here is a work-around that explicitly retrieves the ids within the group and sets the visibility of each retrieved view.

**Within MainActivity.kt**

```
private fun toggleLoginUI(show: Boolean) {
    if (show) {
        setGroupVisibility(mLayout, group, Group.VISIBLE)
    } else {
        setGroupVisibility(mLayout, group, Group.INVISIBLE)
    }
}

private fun setGroupVisibility(layout: ConstraintLayout, group: Group, visibility: Int) {
    val refIds = group.referencedIds
    for (id in refIds) {
        layout.findViewById<View>(id).visibility = visibility
    }
}
```

`mLayout` is the `ConstraintLayout`.

**Update:** Here is another work-around that takes advantage of the fact that changing to/from `GONE` works as expected:

```
private fun toggleLoginUI(show: Boolean) {
    if (show) {
        group.visibility = GONE
        group.visibility = VISIBLE
    } else {
        group.visibility = GONE
        group.visibility = INVISIBLE
    }
}
```

Comment: that works but was hoping for a way that didn't require having to loop through the elements.thanks for the answer.hope it gets resolved.

Comment: @SS2095 If it's a bug then you will have to wait for a future release. (And I think that it is a bug.) This is the best that can be done in the interim if you need that functionality.

Comment: Has somebody reported that bug and has a link to it?

Comment: @TorstenGrote Maybe https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117485026? I also see a reference to a `ConstraintLayout` 2.0 "Layer" feature that may be somehow applicable.

Comment: I actually raised an issue related to this a while ago as I agree with @Cheticamp that this is a bug in the Group class: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130524019

Answer (score 33):

You can also simply call `requestLayout` method after changing Group visibility to `View.INVISIBLE`.

```
fun makeGroupInvisible(group: Group) {
    group.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    group.requestLayout()
}
```

Problem is that `android.support.constraint.Group` updates visibility of its members in `updatePreLayout` method which is called from `onMeasure` in `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: Thx, spent 2 days to find that 'requestLayout()' solver <3

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me, but can this be considered as a bug of constraint layout? Calling requestLayout() after every visibility change seems not quite normal

Comment: group.requestLayout() fixed it for me as well.  That must be a bug

Answer (score 6):

android.support.constraint.Group has a public method

```
 public void updatePreLayout(ConstraintLayout container) {
   ...
 }
```

that updates children visibilities, so calling

```
dataGroup.visibility = if (visible) View.VISIBLE else View.INVISIBLE
dataGroup.updatePreLayout(root)
```

worked for me

Comment: This answer is simple, works and uses a method provided by the library. This should be the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and nothing from above helps. My solution was to `setVisibility(viewId, ConstraintSet.VISIBLE)` inside constraint set and apply that to ConstraintLayout view.

For example:

```
myContstraintSet.apply {
    setVisibility(firstGroup.id, ConstraintSet.VISIBLE)
    setVisibility(secondGroup.id, ConstraintSet.GONE)

    connect(oneView.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, R.id.secondView, ConstraintSet.TOP)
    clear(anotherView.id, ConstraintSet.TOP)
}
myContstraintSet.applyTo(myConstraintLayout)
```

Answer (score 0):

just add follow line you can change it .
so it visible .

```
group.visibility=ConstraintLayout.GONE
```

Comment: I don't agree with this answer, this question is specifically about using View.INVISIBLE. Using ConstraintLayout.GONE is the same as using View.GONE. It's a different type of visibility setting that works.