# Unable to change visibility of view other than onCreate method

Tags: android, visibility, android-camerax

I am unable to change the view visibility inside other function rather than `onCreate` method. Its working only at time of `onCreate` is called.

```
public class CameraXActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
    public Group fipGroup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camerax_layout); // Created xml using constraintLayout.

        //intial setup
        fipGroup = (Group)findViewById(R.id.fip_group);
        startCamera();

        //hideFipGroup(); <<--- This is working
    }

    private void hideFipGroup() {
        Log.d(TAG, "=== hideFipGroup ===");
        fipGroup.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    private void startCamera() {
        CameraX.unbindAll();
        preview = setPreview(); 
        imageAnalysis = setImageAnalysis();

        //bind to lifecycle:
        CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this, preview , imageAnalysis);
        preview.enableTorch(true);
    }

    private ImageAnalysis setImageAnalysis() {
        hideFipGroup() // This is working
        imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(
                new ImageAnalysis.Analyzer() {
                    @Override
                    public void analyze(ImageProxy image, int rotationDegrees) {
                        hideFipGroup() // Exactly, Failed at this place.
                    }
                }
        )
    }

}
```

**Edit Update:**

It's failing to update on the `analyze` method of `imageAnalysis`. Just to test, called toast message which is showing on the UI. But am not able to control the UI.

```
private void raiseToast(String msg) {

        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 500);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I bet there is some tricky/buggy method in "full version" of your code, which is crucial for your case and you have just cutted it out... e.g. some hanging UI code in `startCamera` in place of three dots. posted code is perfectly fine and will work (both calls)

Comment: updated the code snippet. @snachmsm

Comment: when you comment out `CameraX.unbindAll();` line and all below does `startCamera` works? it will only call `hideFipGroup()`

Comment: @snachmsm I have the updated full code. Just traced the issue. It's failed to update on the `analyze` method of imageAnalysis. Any idea how can we handle at this place?

Comment: use `fipGroup.post(...)` method for calling `hideFipGroup` inside `analyze`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [problem](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=117485026) is with Group visibility on constraint Layout.

```
private void setGroupVisiblity(Group group, int visibility) {
   group.setVisibility(visibility);
   group.requestLayout();
}
```

or manually turn off each views in the group:

```
private void setGroupVisibility(ConstraintLayout layout, Group group, Integer visibility) {
     int[] refIds = group.getReferencedIds();
     for (int id : refIds) {
          layout.findViewById(id).setVisibility(visibility);
     }
}
```

or upgrade to [ConstraintLayout version 2.0.0 beta 6](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/05/constraintlayout-200-beta-6.html)

source: [Can't set visibility on constraint group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47865436/cant-set-visibility-on-constraint-group)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to view.post or runOnUIThread method.

so like this.

```
private ImageAnalysis setImageAnalysis() {
    hideFipGroup() // This is working
    imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(
            new ImageAnalysis.Analyzer() {
                @Override
                public void analyze(ImageProxy image, int rotationDegrees) {
                    fipGroup.post(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {
                           hideFipGroup();  // Exactly, Failed at this place.
                       }
                    });
                }
            }
    )
}
```

Or you can simply call view.post() method in hideFipGroup() method

```
private void hideFipGroup() {
    Log.d(TAG, "=== hideFipGroup ===");
    fipGroup.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            fipGroup.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey tried the same to update on the UI thread. But still don't see any changes in the visibility. It executed the `run` method as well.

Comment: Hi, public void analyze(ImageProxy image, int rotationDegrees) method was called?

Comment: Yes. It's getting called for every frame.

Comment: ^ and am hiding it only once based on logic.

Answer (score 0):

you should check the function you called. Remember that you can only update the UI in the main thread

Comment: yeah. trying the same. but no effect on visibility. I can able to trigger the Toast msg on UI. but not sure why am not able to control the UI.