# Multiple Views Vs Multiple Fragments

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm going to create a complex/normal design that has an empty screen layout & shimmer layout.

my question is to have all in one layout with multiple `<include>` files is better than doing two fragments and keep replacing them.

more details:

1- make the data screen shown & empty screen hidden as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/common_toolbar" />

    <include layout="@layout/empty_layout"/>

    // my data layout

</LinearLayout>
```

2- create a `FrameLayout` and keep change the container for different screens with multiple `fragments`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I need to know the best practice as depending on [slow rendering](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render) of multiple views.

another question, is [that](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render) included in for shown/hidden views or it depends on shown ones only as I got confused
and need to apply best practices.

Answer (score 1):

if you attend to reuse some views Fragment is the best, otherwise, if you looking best to render I advise you to use constraint layout and section your views with a group so you can hide and show group 
take a look to this one [How to group multiple views in a ConstraintLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118674/how-to-group-multiple-views-in-a-constraintlayout)

Comment: I know `constarinLayout` does show and hide items affect the UI performance for rendering time?

Comment: No not affect until using complex view as using vedio player or sound player otherwise it seem smoothly

Comment: so, if I've group1 that has a complex design, group2 that has shimmer and group 3 that has an empty screen, all of this in single file this won't make render time slow?

Comment: Until using views like vedio player it's not cause any problems and if you attend to reuse this views in another places I recommend using fragment good luck